# Springfox for wildCard characters in @RestController

Tags: swagger-ui, springfox

How should I handle API endpoints which accepts wildcard characters?

For example I have an endpoint `/version1/resources/**` defined in my controller and this endpoint accepts any string after the `/resource/`.

In my swagger this endpoint looks like this:

```
GET: /version1/resource/**
```

But I don't know how to pass any string to this wildcard character from swagger.
I am using springfox-swagger2 of version 2.5.0